# C# datatable Group by count and distinct

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, count, where-clause

I have a datatable that looks like the one in the picture.

[image]

With the below code I'm trying to count how many units each client id has in the each project. My problem is I can't seem to exclude the duplicate units.

```
var projectsGroup = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(g => g.Field<string>("Project"));
foreach (var projectGroup in projectsGroup)
{
    var clientGroups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(g => g.Field<string>("ClientId"));
    foreach (var clientGroup in clientGroups)
    {
        var test = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(r => r.Field<string>("ClientId") == clientGroup.Key && r.Field<string>("Project") == projectGroup.Key)
            .Select(r => r.Field<string>("Project"));

        //   Console.WriteLine(test.FirstOrDefault() + " " + test.Count());
    }
}
```

So my question is, how can I exclude these from being counted?

Comment: Have you tried using `.Distinct()` and a comparer?

Comment: Hm, I did fiddle abit with .Discticnt() - can you provide an example?

Comment: var result = clientGroups.Select(x=>x.ClientId).Distinct().Count(); ?

Comment: Virtually your entire screenshot was whitespace, which made the text unreadable. I understand that it's a lot of work, but if you absolutely must post text as a screenshot, please crop it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var projectsGroups = dt.AsEnumerable()
                       .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Project"))
                       .Select(pg => new {
                           Project = pg.Key,
                           Clients = pg.GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("ClientId"))
                                       .Select(cg => new {
                                           ClientId = cg.Key,
                                           UnitCount = cg.Select(r => r.Field<string>("Unit"))
                                                          .Distinct()
                                                          .Count()
                                       })
                       })
                       .ToList();

foreach (var pg in projectsGroups) {
    foreach (var client in pg.Clients) {
        Console.WriteLine($"In Project {pg.Project}, Client {client.ClientId} has {client.UnitCount} unit{(client.UnitCount == 1 ? "" : "s")}");
    }
}
```